# Are there exceptions for not crossing solid yellow double lines while driving, such as to pass a parked mail vehicle or horsedrawn carriage?

Tags: united-states, traffic, driving, ohio

I've noticed that in some scenarios, such as when a mail vehicle (USPS, Amazon, etc.) parks on a road or when a horsedrawn carriage is going really slow, and the road has two lanes for each direction separated by solid yellow double lines, that drivers seem to consistently pass despite such being illegal, at least under most circumstances.

Does the law make exceptions under such extreme circumstances?

Comment: The horse drawn carriage should pull in at a good place to let you pass. Crossing a double yellow line should be done with extreme care, legal or not, and only when possible without any danger, considering the double yellow is there for a reason. Legal? Don’t know. People do it? Yes.

Comment: Doesn't it vary by state? Some forbid any crossing of the double-yellow except for obstructions and emergencies. Others allow a left turn into a driveway, or passing a bicycle with care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ohio Revised Code Section 4511.25](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-4511.25) indicates it is acceptable to drive on the left side of the road when there is an obstruction, and it is otherwise safe.

[Section 4511.31](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/section-4511.31) indicates it is acceptable to pass in a no-passing zone if the slower vehicle is traveling less than one-half the speed limit, if it is otherwise safe. It does not contain an explicit exception for obstructions.  It explicitly overrides Section 4511.30, but not 4511.25. It would take some investigation to figure out which section prevails.